# cnt files as image cache on Android?

Tags: android, caching, twitter

I was looking at the image caches on my Android phone to get an idea on how implement mine when I found Twitter's.
Why are their images listed as cnt files? What's a cnt file even? I can't find anything about them on the internet.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Rename to .jpg to see them take .cnt off and put .jpg and it will show the image some games and apps may use .cnt for in app pictures so if it is for a app change it back.